# Shared Views + Forge access - Can I push an Inventor model as a shared view and then access the bucket in a forge app

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I would like to use the Shared Views feature of Vault/AutoCAD/ACADE/Inventor to push models and such (in particular larger Inventor assemblies) up to the cloud, where I assume they land in an OSS bucket.  I think that they are only valid up there for 30 days, but that length of time is fine for my purpose.  What I would like to know is there any way I can get the ID of the bucket, and then use that to view or pull that SVF file into an APP back inside my firewall for further use?  I have some extensions planned in a viewer app back on premises, but I don't have a good way to get the models into the cloud and generated in the first place because of the references in the model - I would have to checkout the model and all references, zip them up, and then send it to the model derivative and such.  I am hoping that since the shared views feature already does that part, I can just leverage that to start my process.

### MORE INFO:

So, using Fiddler I can see several interesting calls related to this.  I went into Vault and created a shared view for a DWG file, then just watched the traffic.    I see calls in a pattern that could be maybe leveraged.

Call 1:

```
GET https://360.autodesk.com/Viewer/GetViewerTranslationById?viewerId=dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u
```

Call 2:

```
GET https://360.autodesk.com/Viewer/GetAccessToken
```

Call 2 returns a token:

```
token_type: "Bearer"
  expires_in: "3599"
  expires_at: "2020-07-17T17:02:15.1187374+00:00"
  access_token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJkYXRhOnJlYWQiLCJkYXRhOndyaXRlIiwiZGF0YTpzZWFyY2giXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiVmZNQ3U1NDg2U3hLQXVRaGRVMU9aYTJuTHdqR1VXcEciLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvand0ZXhwNjAiLCJqdGkiOiI5NVFQYnhGWjlmZ1p0YWxzbXg2OW1oUWczck9WbWRKeDRtZjdtdUY0Z0xBME01TmNqZjJCT1hoa3RiRHdlVm04IiwiZXhwIjoxNTk1MDA1MzQ2fQ.tRQYz7PP-_NIDrZFrWbXvxiP4NfooBHAIC89eQuelkw"
  bucket: "a360viewer"
```

Then Call 3 to the derivatives service:

```
GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u 
.....
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJkYXRhOnJlYWQiLCJkYXRhOndyaXRlIiwiZGF0YTpzZWFyY2giXSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiVmZNQ3U1NDg2U3hLQXVRaGRVMU9aYTJuTHdqR1VXcEciLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvand0ZXhwNjAiLCJqdGkiOiI5NVFQYnhGWjlmZ1p0YWxzbXg2OW1oUWczck9WbWRKeDRtZjdtdUY0Z0xBME01TmNqZjJCT1hoa3RiRHdlVm04IiwiZXhwIjoxNTk1MDA1MzQ2fQ.tRQYz7PP-_NIDrZFrWbXvxiP4NfooBHAIC89eQuelkw
....
```

Call 3 returns lots of information:

```
  guid: "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u"
  owner: "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u"
  hasThumbnail: "true"
  startedAt: "Fri Jul 17 16:06:29 UTC 2020"
  type: "design"
  urn: "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u"
  success: "100%"
  progress: "complete"
  region: "US"
  status: "success"
  children: 
      0: 
          guid: "aa85aad6-c480-4a35-9cbf-4cf5994a25ba"
          hasThumbnail: "true"
          role: "viewable"
          progress: "complete"
          type: "folder"
          status: "success"
          version: "2.0"
          urn: "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u"
          inputFileSize: 1059328
          inputFileType: "collaboration"
          name: "C-424305-036.dwg.dwf"
          success: "100%"
          children: 
              0: 
                  guid: "87CBE465-EAB2-43C0-BA0A-D148B3418FF3_Sheets"
                  type: "folder"
                  name: "Sheets"
                  hasThumbnail: "true"
                  status: "success"
                  progress: "complete"
                  success: "100%"
                  children: 
                      0: 
                          guid: "933b32f8-830d-4861-6e81-294f5d07d4fc"
                          type: "geometry"
                          role: "2d"
                          name: "C-424305-036-Model"
                          status: "success"
                          size: 585718
                          hasThumbnail: "true"
                          progress: "complete"
                          success: "100%"
                          viewableID: "com.autodesk.dwf.ePlot_87CBE466-EAB2-43C0-BA0A-D148B3418FF3"
                          order: 0
                          children: 
                              0: 
                                  urn: "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u/output/933b32f8-830d-4861-6e81-294f5d07d4fc_f2d/primaryGraphics.f2d"
                                  role: "graphics"
                                  size: 503288
                                  mime: "application/autodesk-f2d"
                                  guid: "c7624064-cb61-933b-787c-e02bef313ea4"
                                  type: "resource"
                                  status: "success"
                              1: 
                                  urn: "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u/output/933b32f8-830d-4861-6e81-294f5d07d4fc_f2d/section_properties.db"
                                  role: "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase"
                                  size: 24576
                                  mime: "application/autodesk-db"
                                  guid: "20392091-d0da-d74d-741f-904b078b9c0a"
                                  type: "resource"
                                  status: "success"
                              2: 
                                  guid: "a3a9ad7f-b9aa-451e-8bbc-da2972137d82"
                                  type: "view"
                                  role: "2d"
                                  name: "INITIAL"
                                  viewbox: 
                                      0: 0.67
                                      1: 0.575
                                      2: 16.330833
                                      3: 10.423333
                      1: 
                          guid: "d6e600db-d158-d84f-3101-0a654aa29df3"
                          type: "geometry"
                          role: "2d"
                          name: "C-424305-036-C-424305-036-00"
                          status: "success"
                          size: 617457
                          hasThumbnail: "true"
                          progress: "complete"
                          success: "100%"
                          viewableID: "com.autodesk.dwf.ePlot_87CBE467-EAB2-43C0-BA0A-D148B3418FF3"
                          order: 1
                          children: 
                              0: 
                                  urn: "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u/output/d6e600db-d158-d84f-3101-0a654aa29df3_f2d/primaryGraphics.f2d"
                                  role: "graphics"
                                  size: 535065
                                  mime: "application/autodesk-f2d"
                                  guid: "441471cc-a249-1b4e-36dd-7ea4bff584cd"
                                  type: "resource"
                                  status: "success"
                              1: 
                                  urn: "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90NjM3MzA1OTg3ODExMjQxMTQ4XzQxYjE3M2M1LTVmZjctNDQ2ZC1iNTFkLTgwZTg1NjQ3NjU3ZC5jb2xsYWJvcmF0aW9u/output/d6e600db-d158-d84f-3101-0a654aa29df3_f2d/section_properties.db"
                                  role: "Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase"
                                  size: 24576
                                  mime: "application/autodesk-db"
                                  guid: "03334fbb-15ce-446d-ff80-111dc8616642"
                                  type: "resource"
                                  status: "success"
                              2: 
                                  guid: "69f50589-0774-4cf3-9b21-8164c1e71027"
                                  type: "view"
                                  role: "2d"
                                  name: "INITIAL"
                                  viewbox: 
                                      0: 3.958333
                                      1: 0.4325
                                      2: 16.330833
                                      3: 10.565
```

Further research reveals that the ID used for calling is base64 encoded, decoding it reveals this:

```
urn:adsk.objects:os.object:a360viewer/t637305987811241148_41b173c5-5ff7-446d-b51d-80e85647657d.collaboration
```

Comment: https://360.autodesk.com/viewer is a web app based on Forge  web service, It self has own endpoints to get token , post translation job, get manifest etc. These communicate with Forge services at back-end. So it is not strange with those traffic. Unfortunately,this app has not API to access the data it manages. The os.object:a360viewer is also the private bucket of this app which has not been exposed the accessibility. So it is not supported to download the translated data. Sorry if this is bad news to you

Comment: well, it's not great news, but I do understand the separation.  I will hop over to the ADN forum and suggest a link between the two so that Vault license holders can potentially link these operations together.  It seems like a lot of extra work to have to gather all my files from Vault just to create a view so that I can access it when Vault is capable of sending that already.  Once again, understandable that it is currently separated, that is of no fault on anyone, but it would be great if the systems had more of a useful dialog.